# How to import the app icons, so my app won't be rejected?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I just finished all my app icons for deployment target of iOS 7.1 and iPhone only. But the images.xcassets in my xCode project only has 3 slots. Where do I put the other required icons?
I am referring to this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Since you are building for iPhone, only 3 slots will be appeared. Which are for

- iPhone spotlight and setting (iOS 5/6)
- iPhone spotlight iOS 7
- iPhone app iOS 7

But if you wish to build a universal app, more slots will be appeared.

Comment: So as long as I provide these 3 icons, I will be fine? of course along with the launch image. Also why does apple then state that you need a iTunes network icon(i believe it said 512X512 and a 2x version)?

Comment: is it itunes network icon or iTunes artwork icon? I believe you are referring to the iTunes artwork icon. It doesn't need to bundle into the application. You need to upload it while submitting the application.